# Solr Range Facet is just showing up at xml result

Tags: solr, range, facet

so I set a price range at my solrconfig.xml

```
<str name="facet.range">preis</str>
<int name="f.preis.facet.range.start">0</int>
<int name="f.preis.facet.range.end">1151</int>
<int name="f.preis.facet.range.gap">50</int>
```

The problem is, as the title already said, that this price range just shows up at the XML result site and not at the "normal" one.
As you may can guess, I am new to Solr.
Solr Version 5.4.1

EDIT: This is showing up at my XML result side

```
<lst name="facet_ranges">
<lst name="preis">
<lst name="counts">
<int name="0.0">35267</int>
<int name="50.0">8357</int>
<int name="100.0">3541</int>
```

...

```
<int name="1050.0">136</int>
<int name="1100.0">131</int>
<int name="1150.0">112</int>
</lst>
<float name="gap">50.0</float>
<float name="start">0.0</float>
<float name="end">1200.0</float>
</lst>
</lst>
```

Do i need some more settings so it shows up?

Comment: when you say xml result site and normal result site, are you talking about the response formats, as in XML, JSON etc.?

Comment: @Binoy-Dalal Well , kind off, for me the normal result site is ".../browse" and the other one the one you mentioned (xml result site (format))

Answer (score 0):

`/browse` is a request handler, which autoformats your results and presents them to you in a decent UI, which is why you can "see" the facets.

The "regular" response or the one from the `/select` handler also generates the exact same results for the exact same query but does not format them to a UI which is why you cannot "see" the facets.
If you want to see the facets, you'll have to design a UI which takes this Solr response and then formats it to the UI you've designed.